Get pipeline information by build number with api.bitbucket.org/2.0 api's
I am trying to get pipeline information by build number with:
api.bitbucket.org/2.0 api's
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/repo/pipelines/?q=build_number=1

This returns all the piplines. I just need the one with the build build number of 1.
I tried :
q=%28build_number%3D1

q=build_number%3D1


Try:
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/repo/pipelines/1

